# appendchild and removechild js with AMCHART

Tags: javascript, amcharts

```
     <div id="chartcontainer" >
    <div id="chart" style=" width       : 65%;  height      :  65%;     "></div>
      <div id="curtainpie" style="color:FireBrick;">Chart is loading...</span></div>
    </div>
```

in JS i have:

```
    var curtain = document.getElementById("curtainpie");
          curtain.parentNode.removeChild(curtain);
...........

            curtain.parentNode.appendChild(curtain);
```

so i want to first remove the curtain then later on make it appear again but this doesnt seem to work...(i can remove the curtain but cant make it appear again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a parent node from curtain.

After you remove child `curtain` from `curtain.parentNode`, In your code, 
The just below line code `curtain.parentNode.appendChild(curtain);` cannot find parentNode method because no patents(you removed curtain from parent further.)

Maybe the below code will work.

```
var curtain = document.getElementById("curtainpie");
var parentNode = curtain.parentNode;
parentNode.removeChild(curtain);
parentNode.appendChild(curtain);
```

Comment: thanks man i was about to go nuts i am new to js so i dont know really much but i understood your logic (:

Comment: @shivzuh Learn about reference variables and value in javascript. Then it becomes easy to understand. Have a nice js :)